# Indentation error in python and index out of range error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am getting an indentation error. Can anyone help me to fix it and also getting `tuple index out of range error` too

here is my code

```
def POST(self):
        form = web.input(name="a", newname="s", number="d")
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="testdb")
        x = conn.cursor()
        x.execute("SELECT * FROM details  WHERE name = '%s'" % (form.name))
        conn.commit()
        items = x.fetchall()
        for row in items:
            print row[0], row[1],row[2]
            print("<table border='1'>")
            print("<tr>")
            print("<th>name</th>")
            print("<th>address</th>")
            print("<th>number</th>")
            print("</tr>")
            print("<tr>")
            print("<td>{0}</td>".format(row[0]))
            print("<td>{1}</td>".format(row[1]))
            print("<td>{2}</td>".format(row[2]))
            print("</tr>")
            print("</table>")

            conn.rollback()
            conn.close()
            #return render.index(items)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

am getting error in these lines

```
 print("</tr>")
 print("</table>")
```

Comment: There's no sneaky <tab> character (vs. spaces) is there?

Comment: python indentation error could be caused by mix typing of spaces and tabs, I suggest that you use some exact IDE that can detect spaces and tabs and  type those lines again.

Comment: no no-spaces are there

Comment: i tried retyping it again but  also same error

Comment: If you have a unix shell, try `grep $'\t' script.py` or `grep -E $'^\t* ' script.py` (depending on what indentation you're using). That will highlight the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very basic error.If you are using sublime text.Please select all the rows.
In the beginning of each line of def POST, there will be two patterns.
One is '_____' and '.......' .The pattern should be similar for whole 
 'def POST(self):'
Please make sure this and error will get removed.

Copy and paste this code:

```
    def POST(self):
            form = web.input(name="a", newname="s", number="d")
            conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "localhost", user="root", passwd="", db="testdb")
            x = conn.cursor()
            x.execute("SELECT * FROM details  WHERE name = '%s'" % (form.name))
            conn.commit()
            items = x.fetchall()
            for row in items:
                print row[0], row[1],row[2]
                print("<table border='1'>")
                print("<tr>")
                print("<th>name</th>")
                print("<th>address</th>")
                print("<th>number</th>")
                print("<tr>")
                print("<td>{0}</td>".format(row[0]))
                print("<td>{1}</td>".format(row[1]))
                print("<td>{2}</td>".format(row[2]))
                print("</tr>")
                print("</table>")

                conn.rollback()
                conn.close()
                #return render.index(items)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run()
```

Thanks.

Comment: thank you so much..am totally new in python so thanks for your help and can you just tell me why am getting `tuple index out of range` these error..?

Comment: Your welcome @Edison. Will look into this error also.